# WKHTMLTOPDF - Multiple parameters not allowed?

Tags: parameters, wkhtmltopdf

Im calling wkhtmltopdf from PHP like this:

```
`$commandString = '

"../wkhtmltopdf/wkhtmltopdf-amd64" 

--header-html '. $_SESSION['ER_HlavniLink'] .'/export_pdf/header31.php?IDstavba='.$IDstavba.' 

--header-spacing 0 

--footer-line 

--footer-spacing 5 

--footer-left "Vygenerováno pomocí webové aplikace www.estiroad.cz" 

--footer-center "[page] / [toPage]" 

--orientation Landscape 

--user-style-sheet "../css/export.css" 

--print-media-type 

--page-size A4 

--encoding utf-8

--margin-top 50mm

--margin-bottom 15mm

--margin-left 10mm 

--margin-right 10mm 

'.$_SESSION['ER_HlavniLink'].'/'.$export.' '.$nazev_sestavy;`
```

If I want to add a parameter in the header file call, browser shows me error: Loading of PDF document failed... Can I somehow solve this?

Comment: Could you echo out the complete parsed command string? It's a bit hard to decipher :)

Comment: I don´t know how to do that, output always looks the same...but I formated my original question, so its easier to read now :)

Comment: Thanks. I tested the command and it worked fine for me using wkhtmltopdf 0.11 rc2 on Windows so I don't think that the problem is with the arguments if you are using the same version (I haven't tested it on linux but I would think it works there too). So the problem most likely is with the input HTML, input CSS or output permissions, for example if you can't write to the destination folder. Sorry I can't help more, someone else might be able to help!

Comment: Did you try to add some parameter behind IDstavba? Because the command works for me too, in its current state.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on the comments, I suggest adding double quotes around the --header-html value given. I didn't catch that on the first testing round so thanks to your question, this might help:

This command works:

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --header-html "https://www.google.fi/search?hl=fi&site=&source=hp&q=test&oq=test&gs_l=hp.12..0l10.2413.2773.0.4395.4.4.0.0.0.0.80.232.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.k_PQAqelc9w" --header-spacing 0 --footer-line --footer-spacing 5 --footer-left "Vygenerováno pomocí webové aplikace www.estiroad.cz" --footer-center "[page] / [toPage]" --orientation Landscape --user-style-sheet test.css --print-media-type --page-size A4 --encoding utf-8 --margin-top 50mm --margin-bottom 15mm --margin-left 10mm --margin-right 10mm http://www.google.com/ g2.pdf && g2.pdf
```

This does not (Notice that there are no quotes around the address given to --header-html

```
wkhtmltopdf.exe --header-html https://www.google.fi/search?hl=fi&site=&source=hp&q=test&oq=test&gs_l=hp.12..0l10.2413.2773.0.4395.4.4.0.0.0.0.80.232.4.4.0...0.0...1c.1.k_PQAqelc9w --header-spacing 0 --footer-line --footer-spacing 5 --footer-left "Vygenerováno pomocí webové aplikace www.estiroad.cz" --footer-center "[page] / [toPage]" --orientation Landscape --user-style-sheet test.css --print-media-type --page-size A4 --encoding utf-8 --margin-top 50mm --margin-bottom 15mm --margin-left 10mm --margin-right 10mm http://www.google.com/ g2.pdf && g2.pdf
```

Comment: Thanks! It works... So simple matter :) But I couldn´t see it by myself :)

Comment: That happens a lot! I didn't catch it looking at it the first time, I sometimes even start explaining a problem to a friend or any other person and as I'm trying to explain I find the issue >:) Glad you got it fixed!